# Bigquery data (using SQL) into S3 using Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery world!!!

I have a task to query BigQuery data (SQL Statement) (and open other methods) and upload into S3 bucket.  Find enclosed code for querying data and loading into S3 bucket (not working as expected).  We are trying to avoid data storing into GCS and pull it from there or to use GSUTIL.

Any pointers to examples, or ways to do it is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**Extracting data from BigQuery:**

```
import java.util.UUID
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.{Dataset, JobId, JobInfo, 
QueryJobConfiguration}
import com.gwf.Logging

class BQQuery extends Logging{
    def extractBQData: String  = {
    val bqClient = (new BigQueryClient).createBQClient
    logger.info("projectId: " + bqClient.getOptions.getProjectId)
    val START_DATE = "20180514"
    val END_DATE = "20180514"

    val query = "SELECT " + " FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime+hits.time/1000 AS INT64)), 
    'America/Denver') AS hit_timestamp, " + " FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d 
    %H:%M:%S', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)), 
    'America/Denver') AS hit_visitStartTime, " + " CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,0,4),'- 
    ',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2)) AS date, " + " visitNumber, " + " 
    visitId, " + " fullVisitorId, " + " totals.hits, " + " totals.pageviews, " + 
    " totals.timeOnSite, " + " totals.bounces, " + " totals.newVisits, " + " 
    trafficSource.referralPath, " + " trafficSource.campaign, " + " 
    trafficSource.source, " + " trafficSource.medium, " + " 
    trafficSource.keyword, " + " trafficSource.adContent, " + " device.browser, 
    " + " device.browserVersion, " + " device.browserSize, " + " 
    device.operatingSystem, " + " device.operatingSystemVersion, " + " 
    device.isMobile, " + " device.mobileDeviceBranding, " + " 
    device.flashVersion, " + " device.javaEnabled, " + " device.language, " + " 
    device.screenColors, " + " device.screenResolution, " + " 
    device.deviceCategory, " + " geoNetwork.continent, " + " 
    geoNetwork.subContinent, " + " geoNetwork.country, " + " geoNetwork.region, 
    " + " geoNetwork.metro, " + " hits.type, " + " hits.hitNumber, " + " 
    hits.social.socialInteractionNetwork, " + " 
    hits.social.socialInteractionAction, " + " hits.time/1000 AS hits_time, " + 
    " hits.hour, " + " hits.minute, " + " hits.isSecure, " + " 
    hits.isInteraction, " + " hits.isEntrance, " + " hits.isExit, " + " 
    hits.referer, " + " hits.page.pagePath, " + " hits.page.hostname, " + " 
    hits.page.pageTitle, " + " hits.page.searchKeyword, " + " 
    hits.page.searchCategory, " + " hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, " + " 
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction, " + " hits.eventInfo.eventLabel, " + " 
    hits.eventInfo.eventValue, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS LIAT_event_source_cd1, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=2, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    LIAT_event_id_cd2, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=3, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Slider_id_cd3, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=4, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    Individual_id_cd4, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=5, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Plan_id_cd5, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=6, 
    value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Terminated_status_cd6, 
    " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=7, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS LIAT_Slider_Changed_Element_cd7, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=8, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    LIAT_Page_Name_cd8, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=9, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Login_Status_cd9, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=10, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    Debug_cd10, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=11, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Age_cd11, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=12, 
    value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Salary_Group_cd12, " + 
    " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=13, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) 
    AS Gender_cd13, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=14, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS TransactionId_cd14, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=15, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    Transaction_User_Id_cd15, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=16, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Unique_Event_Id_cd16, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=17, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    not_set_dimension_cd17, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=18, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS ValueUnits_cd18, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=19, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    Deferral_Type_Code_cd19, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=20, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Income_Term_cd20, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=21, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    Plan_Name_cd21, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=22, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Company_Match_Rule_cd22, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=23, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    Company_Match_Description_cd23, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=24, value, NULL)) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Has_Company_Match_cd24, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=25, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    TimeStamp_cd25, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=26, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS Enrollment_Type_cd26, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=27, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    test_Liat_Page_cd27, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=28, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS hdic_ageselection_cd28, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=29, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    hdic_salaryselection_cd29, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=30, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS hdic_genderselection_cd30, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=31, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    hdic_my_pct_goal_cd31, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=32, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS hdic_mycontribution_cd32, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=33, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    hdic_mybalance_cd33, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=34, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS hdic_peer_pctgoal_cd34, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=35, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS 
    hdic_peer_contributionrate_cd35, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=36, value, 
    NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS hdic_peer_balance_cd36, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=37, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) 
    AS hdic_top_pct_goal_cd37, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=38, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS hdic_top_contributionrate_cd38, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=39, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) 
    AS hdic_top_balance_cd39, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=40, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS AgeRange_cd40, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Slider_value_cm1, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=2, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Slider_previous_value_cm2, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=3, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Slider_Users_cm3, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=4, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Slider_End_Value_cm4, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=5, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Slider_Start_Value_cm5, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=6, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Saved_Retirement_Age_Start_Value_cm6, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=7, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Saved_Retirement_Age_End_Value_cm7, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=8, value, 
    NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Saved_Deferral_Rate_Start_Value_cm8, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=9, value, 
    NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Saved_Deferral_Rate_End_Value_cm9, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=10, value, 
    NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Equity_Start_Value_cm10, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=11, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Equity_End_Value_cm11, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=12, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Bond_Start_Value_cm12, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=13, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Bond_End_Value_cm13, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=14, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Salary_cm14, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=15, 
    value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Deferral_Rate_Change_Pct_cm15, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=16, value, NULL)) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS BNS_Recommended_Dollar_cm16, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=17, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    BNS_Recommended_Pct_cm17, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=18, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Participant_Age_cm18, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=19, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Estimated_Monthly_Income_cm19, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=20, value, NULL)) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Percent_of_Goal_cm20, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=21, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Income_Goal_cm21, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=22, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Income_Gap_cm22, " + " (SELECT 
    MAX(IF(index=23, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    test_Avg_Deferral_Start_cm23, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=24, value, NULL)) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS test_Avg_Deferral_End_cm24, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=25, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Goal_Base_Salary_New_cm25, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=26, value, NULL)) FROM 
    UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Goal_Percent_Of_Salary_New_cm26, " + " 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=27, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS 
    Goal_Base_Salary_Previous_cm27, " + " (SELECT MAX(IF(index=28, value, NULL)) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits.customMetrics)) AS Goal_Percent_Of_Salary_Previous_cm28, " 
    + "  hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName, " + "  
    hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId " + " FROM `<ProjectID>. 
    <DataSetId>.ga_sessions_*` , UNNEST(hits) as hits " + " WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
    BETWEEN '" + START_DATE + "' AND '" + END_DATE + "' LIMIT 5"
    val queryConfig = 
    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).setUseLegacySql(false).build()


    logger.info("query:" + query)
    val jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString)
    logger.info("Jobid:" + jobId)

    val bQry =   
        bqClient.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig)
        .setJobId(jobId).build()).getBigQuery


    /*var queryJob = 
    bqClient.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build())
    queryJob = queryJob.waitFor()

    if (queryJob.getStatus.getError != null) {
    //TODO:
    } else if (queryJob == null) {
    //TODO:
    }
    */
    bQry.getDataset(queryConfig.getDefaultDataset).toString
}
```

**Reading JSON data into DataFrame:**

```
<code>

def loadDataFromGoogleAnalytics : DataFrame = {
    env.sparkSession
  .read
  .json((new BQQuery).extractBQData)
  .toDF()
}

</code>
```

Comment: Any takers... any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you confirm: you want to upload your results of the query directly to Amazon S3 without using Google Cloud Storage bucket? On which step your code returns an error or what step you are missing from your code?